# AjaxAutoComplete not working after migration to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, autocompleteextender

My autocomplete works fine when using my old site but does not work when I ported over to C# and Entity Framework.  The below HTML is part of a user control.   I've put breakpoints in the webservice code and it doesn't even look like it's getting called.  I don't know where else to check to see where the break is.   Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDamName" runat="server" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBoxDamName_AutoCompleteExtender"
                        runat="server"
                        DelimiterCharacters="" 
                        Enabled="True" 
                        ServicePath="DamSafetyAutoComplete.asmx"
                        ServiceMethod="SelectDamNames" 
                        FirstRowSelected="True" 
                        MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
                        CompletionInterval="200"
                        TargetControlID="TextBoxDamName">
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender></td>

namespace ExternalDamSafetySearch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for DamSafetyAutoComplete
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class DamSafetyAutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        public string[] SelectDamNames(string prefixText, Int32 count)
        {
            try
            {
                EnterprisePubEntities EE = new EnterprisePubEntities();

                return EE.DamSafetyDatas
                    .Take(count)
                    .Where(c => c.DamName.StartsWith(prefixText))
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(c => c.DamName)
                    .Select(c => c.DamName)
                    .ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most browsers allow you to see network requests. For instance, in Chrome you can press `CTRL + SHIFT + J` to bring up the console. Then click the Network tab. As you type, check if any outbound requests are being made to your autocomplete service.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you I forgot about Fiddler so I used it and I was able to see that a call was being made but to the wrong location.  Fixed that and now I'm getting into the service but not getting the results returned.  I'm willing to bet it's how I'm converting the results to an array.  So, onto the next issue.   Thanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: I wasn't returning it correctly.  I changed my ToArray line to return damNames.ToList().ToArray(); and all is well.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer and accept it yourself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't directing the control to the correct locatioin for my Webservice file.  Once I fixed that I still wasn't getting results even though I was hitting the method in the webservice.   Turns out I wasn't return the results correctly.  I fixed it by turning this

```
            return EE.DamSafetyDatas
                .Take(count)
                .Where(c => c.DamName.StartsWith(prefixText))
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(c => c.DamName)
                .Select(c => c.DamName)
                .ToArray();
```

to

```
            return EE.DamSafetyDatas
                 .Where(c => c.DamName.StartsWith(prefixText))
                .Distinct().Take(count)
                .OrderBy(c => c.DamName)
                .Select(c => c.DamName)
                .ToList.ToArray();
```

I also had to change the location of the .Take(count) because it would take the first (count = 10) from the list THEN filter them by starts with.